# Difference between tokens retrieved via #onNewToken and #getToken

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to register a firebase application instance to an fcm notification group, following https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group. I have to provide a field, "registeration_ids".

My understanding is that I have to pass in the application instance's token to this field, so fcm can send out messages on behalf of this firebase instance. However, I don't know whether I need to use the token I get through `FcmMessagingService#onNewToken(String token)`, or the token I get through `FcmInstanceId#getToken(String senderId, String scope)`.

Are they different in any way? Is the second option there just to allow us to restrict the scope of the retrieved token?

Answer (score 1):

Those method should be returning a token in the same format, and usually the same value.

The difference is in the approach of how you get the token:

- Calling `getToken` means that you determine when to get the token.
- Implementing `onNewToken` means that FCM calls you when it has a (initial or new) token.

You definitely need `onNewToken` as the token may get refreshed when the user isn't actively using your app, and you'll need to relay that new token to your servers.

Implementing `getToken()` is really useful during development as often the token will already have been generated before you implement `onNewToken`. So in that case calling `getToken()` when your main activity starts is the common way to register it with the server.

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your answer! I'm still a bit confused, because `getToken` allows the user to specify a scope, while `onNewToken` does not. Can you provide some insight on why that is?

Comment: I've never used the scope as far as I recall. From the docs it seems only for sending messages, which I only do through the server-side APIs.