# Confusion in Firebase messaging token documentation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We can get current token by calling this piece of code,

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
          if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Fetching FCM registration token failed", task.getException());
            return;
          }

          // Get new FCM registration token
          String token = task.getResult();

          // Log and toast
          String msg = getString(R.string.msg_token_fmt, token);
          Log.d(TAG, msg);
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

But firebase tells us to register a service which listens for onNewToken() callback
It says that new token might be generated under following scenarios

```
There are two scenarios when onNewToken is called:
 * 1) When a new token is generated on initial app startup
 * 2) Whenever an existing token is changed
 * Under #2, there are three scenarios when the existing token is changed:
 * A) App is restored to a new device
 * B) User uninstalls/reinstalls the app
 * C) User clears app data
```

I'm confused that if there programmatic access to token, then why there is a service called on token change since there is no condition where token changes mid session !! Can anyone explain with use cases of both of the things above?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62525679/20447561) that explained the difference between the two.